# Error removing child element

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of input boxes and a button at the last input box to add more input boxes which. I have a problem removing the button when the add button is clicked.

http://gist.github.com/621417

I am getting this error on trying to removing a child element.

**Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMHTMLDivElement.removeChild]"  nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)"  location: "JS frame**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are first creating the `addBtn` element, you are only setting the `name` property.

You need to set the `id` property as well.

So, in `createCreditBalanceInputs`, change the code to include this line (`addBtn.id = "addBtn";`):

```
var addBtn = document.createElement('input');
addBtn.type = 'button';
addBtn.style.marginLeft = "20px";
addBtn.style.marginTop = "5px";
addBtn.name="addBtn";
addBtn.id = "addBtn";
addBtn.value="Add";
```

Then, you don't need to create the button every time.  You can just keep appending it and the DOM hooks will automatically remove it from its previous position.  You can change `addCreditBalance` to look more like this:

```
var addButton = document.getElementById('addBtn');
/*
//Add button
var addBtn = document.createElement('input');
addBtn.type = 'button';
addBtn.style.marginLeft = "20px";
addBtn.style.marginTop = "5px";
addBtn.name="addBtn";
addBtn.value="Add";
addBtn.addEventListener ('click',addCreditBalance,false);
*/
container.appendChild(addButton);
```

and remove the earlier line where you invoked the `removeChild` call.